# How to make application remember To-do data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked about for quite a while now, and nothing seems to work or fit my current problem.

I am creating a To-Do project and I want chrome to remember your To-Dos, even if you refresh the browser.

I have tried a few methods, but this is where I am at the moment. The javascript updates the localstorage everytime the 'createPost' function is called, and then it is loaded by the code at the bottom (i flagged the relavant lines).

View the updated demo here: https://dominicody.netlify.app/todo/
( the main website isnt finished so dont judge please lol)

```js
let form = document.getElementById("todo-form");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let msg = document.getElementById("msg");
let todos = document.getElementById("todos");
let right = document.getElementById("right")
let noToDo = document.getElementById("notodo")
let counter = 0; /* new line */

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("button clicked");

  formValidation();
});

let formValidation = () => {
  if (input.value === "") {
    msg.innerHTML = "To-Do cannot be blank";
  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = "";
    acceptData();
  }
};

let data = [];

let acceptData = () => {
  data = [...data, {
    "text": input.value
  }];
  input.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem('todoItemsRef', JSON.stringify(data));
  createToDo(data[data.length - 1]);
};

let createToDo = () => {
  counter++; /* new line */
  todos.innerHTML += `
    <div>
      <p>${data.text}</p>
      <span class="options">
        <i onClick="completedToDo(this)" class='bx bx-check-circle'></i>
        <i onClick="editToDo(this)" class='bx bx-edit-alt'></i>
        <i onClick="deleteToDo(this)" class='bx bx-trash' ></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    `;
  input.value = "";
};


let completedToDo = (e) => {
  e.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('completed')
}

let deleteToDo = (e) => {
  e.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

  counter--;
  if (counter === 0) {
    showNoToDo();
  }
};

let editToDo = (e) => {
  input.value = e.parentElement.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
  e.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
};

let hideNoToDo = () => {
  noToDo.classList.add('hidden')
  form.classList.remove('form-reg-position')
}

let showNoToDo = () => {
  noToDo.classList.remove('hidden')
  form.classList.add('form-reg-position')
}

/*     localStorage.setItem('todoItemsRef', JSON.stringify(data)); */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ref = localStorage.getItem('todoItemsRef');
  if (ref) {
    data = JSON.parse(ref);
    data.forEach(t => {
      createToDo(t);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=League+Spartan:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Noto+Serif:wght@400;700&display=swap');
:root {
  --primary-color: rgb(240, 69, 114);
  --primary-color-ligh: rgb(220, 100, 124);
  --secondary-color: rgb(25, 24, 44);
  --secondary-color-ligh: rgb(64, 64, 83);
  --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --primary-font: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
  --secondary-font: 'Noto Serif', serif;
  --kanit-font: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  --swiper-theme-color: rgb(240, 69, 114);
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 4rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.todo-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 70%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.no-todo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.no-todo img {
  width: 150px;
}

.no-todo p {
  font-family: var(--primary-font);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.no-todo p2 {
  font-family: var(--primary-font);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.no-todo.hidden {
  display: none;
}

form {
  margin-left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  ;
}

.textarea {
  margin-top: 24px;
  min-width: 95%;
  max-width: 95%;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.form-reg-position {
  transform: translateY(250%) translateX(-50%);
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

.textarea::placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

#todos div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: var(--kanit-font);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #000;
}

#todos div.completed {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  color: #000;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}

i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* TOP NAV */

.top-nav-img-only {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.top-nav-img-only a img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>bydom</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/todo/todo.css">
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="top-nav-img-only">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="/images/logo.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <h1>todos</h1>
  <div class="no-todo" id="notodo">
    <img src="/svg/checklist.svg">
    <p>Add your first To-Do</p>
    <p2>What's first on your list?</p2>
  </div>
  <div class="todo-main">
    <form class="form-reg-position" id="todo-form">
      <br><br>
      <input class="textarea" type="text" name="todo" id="input" placeholder="Add new To-do"></input>
      <br><br>
      <div id="msg"></div>
    </form>
    <div id="todos">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="/todo/todo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you would have to utilize localstorage or some sort of db to ensure your todos were maintained regardless of the browser refreshing

Comment: try to make your data variable as an object.You are using `var data = []` and trying to add property into it change it to `var data = {}`

Comment: @AnkitPandey I changed it and nothing happens. When I open inspect and go to Application>Storage>LocalStorage All it reads is Key - todoItemsRef Value-[]

Comment: im noticing when you create a todo an empty array is getting stored in localstorage, you aren't actually pushing the todos into your data array either when creating a todo.  Same can be said for when you edit/delete as well, you aren't updating local storage either.

Comment: @RobTerrell , I understand what you mean. Any idea on how to incorporate this into the code? maybe something such as data.push(data.text)?

Comment: You are not saving any data because if your stringify your `data` array, it comes up empty. The `data` variable should be an array, however it should be an array of objects. Replace `data["text"] = input.value;` with `data.push({"text": input.value})` (or for a more modern version `data = [...data, {"text": input.value}]`). Also your `renderTodo` function doesn't appear to be declared so it won't load anything either.

Comment: The code you provided also appears to be incomplete in your js file.  renderTodo isn't defined and a few other items aren't even used.  Is there a more complete version

Comment: @RobTerrell @EssXTee Apologies, I meant createToDo. I replaced it and it partly works, but only when i use `data["text"] = input.value;` or `data = [...data, {"text": input.value}]`. This is a problem because the note then only says 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is update Local Storage whenever you change something in the tasks.

You can create a function to update Local Storage and this function will be called whenever you update something in the tasks, when you mark it as complete and when you delete a task.

```
const updateLocalStorage = () => {

}
```

This function will pick up all the tasks that are on the screen

Add task in Local Storage

```
localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify([...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]"), { task: task.value, completed: false }]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few issues with the example/code provided, but the main thing seems to be how you were trying to store the *todo* list. Your list was an array called `data` and when each new *todo* item was created, it would overwrite the previous value of `data["text"]`. Also, because of the way you structured your array (which was more like an object), you could not `stringify` the list.

So the first fix was to make your array an array of objects `[{},{}]`. This would allow each item on the list to have its own **text** value.

Another issue was calling a function that didn't exist `renderTodo`. (*OP did mention in a comment this was later corrected*).

There are also a lot of weird ways some of the code is structured, but with all of that aside, here is a basic example of what you seem to need. I removed functions and code that wasn't necessary for the question asked. This solution will save your todo list in `localStorage` and load it when the page loads. Anything else is a different question/topic.

```js
let form = document.getElementById("todo-form"),
input = document.getElementById("input"),
msg = document.getElementById("msg"),
todos = document.getElementById("todos"),
data = [];

form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formValidation();
});

let formValidation = () => {
  if (input.value === "") {
    msg.innerHTML = "To-Do cannot be blank";
  } else {
    msg.innerHTML = "";
    acceptData();
  }
};


let acceptData = () => {
  data = [...data, {"text": input.value}];
  input.value = "";
  localStorage.setItem('todoItemsRef', JSON.stringify(data));
  renderTodo(data[data.length-1]);
};

let renderTodo = (t) => {
  let todo = document.createElement("div");
  todo.innerHTML = `<p>${t.text}</p>`;
  todos.append(todo);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ref = localStorage.getItem('todoItemsRef');
  if(ref) {
    data = JSON.parse(ref);
    data.forEach(t => {
      renderTodo(t);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(240, 69, 114);
    --primary-color-ligh: rgb(220, 100, 124);
    --secondary-color: rgb(25, 24, 44);
    --secondary-color-ligh: rgb(64, 64, 83);
    --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --primary-font: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
    --secondary-font: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    --kanit-font: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    --swiper-theme-color: rgb(240, 69, 114);
}


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'League Spartan', sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 4rem;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.todo-main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 75%;
    height: 70%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.textarea {
  margin-top: 24px;
  min-width: 95%;
  max-width: 95%;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.7s;
}

form {
  margin-left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
#todos div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: var(--kanit-font);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid var(--secondary-color);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>todos</h1>
<div class="todo-main">
  <form class="form-reg-position" id="todo-form">
    <br><br>
    <input class="textarea" type="text" name="todo" id="input" placeholder="Add new To-do">
    <br><br>
    <div id="msg"></div>
  </form>
<div id="todos"></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE** *This example will not run on Stack Overflow because of a lack of access to the `localStorage` object.*

**EDIT** I also have a [relevant CodePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/xxWeavV) with more of the original code for reference. `localStorage` will function in this CodePen example.

Comment: As the renderToDo function was supposed to be the createToDo function, I tried to apply your code by switching out a few of the names, but it still gives me 'undefined' It may be due to how ive phrased the code, so I updated the question with what I have so far

Comment: @turtles I modified the render function to instead take an item from the `data` array and add it to the page. It made more sense to me to clear the input field and update `localStorage` in the `acceptData` function, and then have a separate render function that can be used for adding and loading. I'll link a CodePen here shortly that may be more helpful.

Comment: that would be extremely helpful. As I'm not using the renderToDo function, but the createToDo function instead (you can see the example in the code) is there anyway to change a few stuff so I dont use the renderToDo function? Or does it need to stay

Comment: @turtles The name of the function honestly doesn't matter. The concept is more important. In your `createToDo` function you are saving the `data` variable in `localStorage` and clearing out the input field. When the page loads, the `createToDo` function will preform these tasks unncessarily. The idea is to break up functions based on what they ***need*** to do, and only call them when needed. [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/xxWeavV) is a more complete example.

Comment: just checked everything and it works great. Added some of the original code so it hides the empty page holder but otherwise amazing! However the code you added to remove the todo from the localstorage doesnt work for some reason. I'll try see if  I can fix it but if you can please take a look at it. Thank you for your help so far